# How to format the data displayed in android app from a mysql database

Tags: android, mysql

I am trying to display details from a remote mysql database using php to my android app. Everything is working fine except that the fields appear in a disorganized manner. Below is a screen shot of the way the data is displayed.

I would like the fields to be displayed in a more organised manner.for example,

> "first name:pk  last name:mungaih  crime_id:12   location:washington
>   id number:123456"

Help will be highly appreciated.Regards

Comment: please add the missing screen shot...

Comment: I noticed the screen shot did not upload.Here is an example of how the data is displayed    "lname:"pk","crime_id":"12","loaction":"Washington" "id_no":"123456"

Comment: Please add more info to the question.. Like what is the response format (is it JSON?) post a sample response that is coming form the server and identify the problem in the response...

Comment: can i upload the code if its not too much to ask.The response is json

Comment: JSON lib cannot preserve the order of the element in the JSON object.. see my answer.. why do you want them to be in some particular order? you can use any JSON lib to parse the response...

Comment: seems am having issues posting the code. I want to fetch the database field values only and then display them next to field names i will assing in my android code.In my case however,the column names of the database are also displayed

Answer (score 0):

You cannot and should not rely on the ordering of elements within a JSON object.

From the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/)

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

As a consequence, JSON libraries are free to re-arrange the order of the elements as they see fit. This is not a bug.

You can use any JSON lib to parse the response without worrying abut the order of the elements in the JSON object (response).

Comment: would you assist me on how to rectify this?i would really appreciate.thanks

Comment: I am still not been able to understand you problem... what is the issue? is the issue is in the parsing json? is the issue is in creating UI from the parsed JSON response? ...

Comment: kindly provide me with your email adress so i can post some screem=n shots.This will help.

Comment: please post in your question so that other people can also see it and help you...